# R function possible roundoff error

Tags: r

I am trying to write a function that sets a lower level cutoff"

```
trunc1 <- function(x,threshold) ifelse(x<=threshold,0,x)
df<-data.frame(a=seq(0,1,0.1),b=seq(0.05,1.05,0.1))
```

when I run:

```
trunc1(df$a,0.5)
```

I get

```
0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.6 0.7 0.8 0.9 1.0
```

which is what I expect.  However,

```
trunc1(df$a,0.6)
```

returns

```
0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.6 0.7 0.8 0.9 1.0
```

I am surprised by this since 0.6<=0.6 the ifelse function should have returned 0 not 0.6.  I know this should be simple.

```
x<-seq(0,1,0.1)<=0.6
names(x)<-seq(0,1,0.1)
```

returns

```
   0   0.1   0.2   0.3   0.4   0.5   0.6   0.7   0.8   0.9     1 
TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

version
               _
platform       x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0
arch           x86_64
os             darwin15.6.0
system         x86_64, darwin15.6.0
status
major          3
minor          4.3
year           2017
month          11
day            30
svn rev        73796
language       R
version.string R version 3.4.3 (2017-11-30)
nickname       Kite-Eating Tree

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9508518/why-are-these-numbers-not-equal

Comment: `format(seq(0,1,0.1)[7], digits = 22); format(.6, digits = 22)`

Comment: I hate floats. I'll try rounding to 10 digits that did it.  Can you make this an answer so I can accept it.